# I am trying to find if a given key is present or not in a binary tree. I want to return the pointer to node if the key is present

Tags: c++11, recursion, binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to find if a given key is present or not in a binary tree. I want to return the pointer to node if the key is present. I am unable to decide how to carry forward the key once found.

```
Node* findNode(Node*root,int ele){

    if(!root)
        return NULL;
    if(root->data==ele)
        return root;
    findNode(root->left,ele);
    findNode(root->right,ele);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am unable to decide how to carry forward the key once found.

The way to *carry forward* something from a function is to `return` it. You can change

```
    findNode(root->left,ele);
    findNode(root->right,ele);
```

to

```
    Node *node;
    (node = findNode(root->left, ele)) || (node = findNode(root->right, ele));
    return node;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I tried the above, but the assignment you are doing is a bool to Node* type.So it won't work.

Comment: You must have made a copy-and-paste error. Both assignments assign the return value of `findNode()` to `node`, all of which are of type `Node *`, none is a _bool_.

Comment: My bad, it worked ! Thanks a lot ! Can you explain what does the OR operator  here ?